# How to create an auto incrementing string?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I facing an issue to increment an string with 01, 02, ..., 10, 12

- I have a SQL query which is giving me `AAAA06` which is max in my database.
- Now I have an requirement that, whenever user call this one, it will check the database with max no. which currently is `AAAA06`(is the max currently) and should return or print `AAAA07`.
- Similarly when the max is `AAAA09` then it should increment to `AAAA10` and so on
- As a language I am using Java but I want to know can I achieve this with my sql query it self or have to write Java code to achieve this?

My query I am using is like

```
select max(code) from mt_users where maincode='AAAA'
```

Calling the max no is done by me; I just want to increment or concatenate whatever it suits to get the desire output.

It returns me `AAAA06` as this one is the max currently.

**Important points**

1. When initially it is `AAAA` the it should show `AAAA01`
2. When it is `AAAA09` it should show `AAAA10`
3. when it is `AAAA99` it will show `AAAA100`

**Note:** currently I have max as `AAAA06` but for new user in future it can be AAAE so I have to start it with `AAAE01`.

Comment: What is the datatype of that field in the DB?

Comment: @Hannes it is varchar

Comment: You already seem to have the field `mainode` (btw, s that meant to be "mainnode" or "maincode"?) which contains the "AAAA" prefix. So can't you just have a numeric field that autoincrements at access and return a concatenation of both?

Comment: @Thomas i don't know how to achieve that

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor (i.e. back-to-front) design.

Comment: @Strawberry that is the design of DB which is done by someone now i have to achieve this :(

Comment: @SalmanA it is `AAAA99` not `AAA99`..........it will show `AAAA100`

Comment: @munish then you will have trouble finding max value. `SELECT MAX(s) FROM (SELECT 'AAAA100' s UNION SELECT 'AAAA21') x` returns `AAAA21`!!!

Comment: @SalmanA no on selecting max for `AAAA100` it is giving `AAAA100` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -- use this query:

```
SELECT id AS PrevID, CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(id, 1, 4),
    IF(CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) <= 9, '0', ''),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) + 1
) AS NextID
FROM (
    -- since you allow strings such as AAAA20 and AAAA100 you can no longer use MAX
    SELECT id
    FROM t
    ORDER BY SUBSTRING(id, 1, 4) DESC, CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) x
```

Results:

```
| PrevID  | NextID  | 
| AAAA100 | AAAA101 | 
| AAAA21  | AAAA22  | 
| AAAA06  | AAAA07  |
```

---

Just for the fun, I wrote this stored procedure that generates *numbers* that look like `AAAA00 AAAA99 AAAB00` etc:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NextID(PrevID VARCHAR(6))
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
BEGIN
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(4);
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE j INT;

    SET s = LEFT(PrevID, 4);
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'A', '0');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'B', '1');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'C', '2');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'D', '3');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'E', '4');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'F', '5');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'G', '6');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'H', '7');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'I', '8');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'J', '9');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'K', 'A');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'L', 'B');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'M', 'C');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'N', 'D');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'O', 'E');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'P', 'F');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'Q', 'G');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'R', 'H');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'S', 'I');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'T', 'J');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'U', 'K');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'V', 'L');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'W', 'M');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'X', 'N');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'Y', 'O');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'Z', 'P');

    SET i = RIGHT(PrevID, 2);
    SET j = CONV(s, 26, 10);

    SET i = i + 1;
    IF i > 99 THEN
        SET i = 0;
        SET j = j + 1;
    END IF;

    SET s = CONV(j, 10, 26);
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'P', 'Z');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'O', 'Y');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'N', 'X');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'M', 'W');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'L', 'V');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'K', 'U');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'J', 'T');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'I', 'S');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'H', 'R');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'G', 'Q');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'F', 'P');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'E', 'O');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'D', 'N');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'C', 'M');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'B', 'L');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, 'A', 'K');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '9', 'J');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '8', 'I');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '7', 'H');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '6', 'G');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '5', 'F');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '4', 'E');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '3', 'D');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '2', 'C');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '1', 'B');
    SET s = REPLACE(s, '0', 'A');

    RETURN CONCAT(LPAD(s, 4, 'A'), LPAD(i, 2, '0'));
END

SELECT NextID('AAAA01') -- AAAA02
SELECT NextID('AAAA99') -- AAAB00
SELECT NextID('AAAB99') -- AAAC00
SELECT NextID('AAAZ99') -- AABA00
```

Comment: id/PrevID is the column that contains the string. NextID is the "generated" id based on previous id (added for demonstration).

Comment: hey when there is `BBBB` it is going to give `BBBB01` ?

Comment: hey sir i have a very small issue..whenever you ll be free please comment here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lpad` as

```
select case when code < 10 
            then concat( substring(maincode,1,4),lpad( max(code)+1 ,length(code+10),'0')) 
            else concat( substring(maincode,1,4),lpad( max(code)+1 ,length(code+1),'0')) 
            end
    as "Result String"
  from tab
 where maincode = 'AAAA01' -- 'AAAE';
```

*Depending on the chat among us, you need the following logic :*

```
select concat( substring(maincode,1,4), 
                     case when substring(maincode,5,length(maincode)-4) !=
                               substring(maincode,5,length(maincode)-4)+1
                     then
                         substring(maincode,5,length(maincode)-4)+1
                     else
                      lpad( 
                         substring(maincode,5,length(maincode)-4)+1,
                      length(maincode)-4,'0')
                     end
                )               
    as "Result String"
  from tab;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/MLSCM41365)</kbd>

Comment: hey sir it is giving wrong result as for `AAAA06` it is it is giving `AAAA0601`

Comment: @manishthakur are you sure dear friend, consider the demo please.

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: hey sir for `AAAA` it is giving  `AAAA01` but for `AAAA01` it is giving null as in where clause maincode=`AAAA01` it display null,you can check

Comment: same issue sir giving AAAA1 insted of AAAA01 and for AAAA01 it is giving null

Comment: @manishthakur OK, got the issue, and fixed now. You can try with `0,1,..9,98,99,100...` ...

Comment: sir still the same issue when passing maincode as `AAAA01` it shows null :(

Comment: i think  there is some misunderstanding

Comment: @manishthakur from the question's text, I understand that there are two seperate columns called **maincode** and **code**, and my answer depends on this logic.